# How to convert a PIL ImageDraw to Image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a PIL image:

```py
img=Image.open(...)
```

that I convert to an `ImageDraw` to write in it.

```
img=ImageDraw.Draw(img)
```

Now I put the text in:

```
img.text((0,0), 'text', (0,0,0))
```

and now I want it **BACK AS AN IMAGE**

I was hoping for something like this:

```
img = Image.fromdraw(img)
```

I need my image in this format, for further processing.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[ImageDraw](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.Draw) draws on your original image, therefore you should keep both instances (Image and ImageDraw objects) in separate variables.

```
img = Image.open(...)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0,0), 'text', (0,0,0))
# img is modified inplace
```

Comment: Perfect. This did not occur to me in 60 min of debugging. MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
img = Image.open(...)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img) 
draw.text((0,0), 'text', (0,0,0))
img.show()
img.save("ImageDrawn.png")
```

Draw is used to draw over image. When drawing in draw object it draws over the img.

Comment: thanks. for the answer. I do not need to save the image though but feed it in a pipeline that only works with `Image` but not with `ImageDraw`. So I do not want to save the `ImageDraw` to the hard drive just to read it again as an `Image`. That is too much I/O usage. and export / import `PIL` with numpy is also super annoying. I really need ImageDraw -> Image

Comment: Oh, sorry. I added the part with saving because I tested it on mine and wanted to check. Its done in-place as the answer above specifies.